# Can you use malloc() after delete() in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc

I have recently been learning about pointers and I was wondering if after you use delete() you can use malloc() again. I am currently learning this so I can be more experienced in C++ and so I can program like the older developers back in the 1990’s

Comment: If you're doing C++ today you absolutely don't want to do it 1990s style. C++ has changed dramatically since those days and offers conveniences that you do not want to ignore. In particular, C++ places an emphasis on avoiding allocations via `new` and instead steers towards objects that are *cheap to copy*, where any allocations are neatly contained within them and moved/duplicated as necessary. It's worth finding resources on so-called "Effective C++" as these are important concepts to keep in mind when writing maintainable C++.

Comment: Yes, you can use `malloc` after a `delete`.  There is no guarantee about how the memory is managed, except when you are finished with the dynamic memory, you should return it:  `malloc->free`, `new->delete`.  You can also call `malloc` many times before calling `free`.  Also, calling `delete` on memory allocated by `malloc` is undefined behavior; consider them two separate systems and don't cross the streams.

Comment: Side note: Do not conflate the pointer with the object it points at. Always keep in your head that they are two separate objects. The first object, the pointer, merely tells you where to find the second object. Mind you that assumes that the pointer actually points at an object. This cannot be guaranteed in the general case, and one of the reason raw pointers are frowned on in modern programming.

Comment: Programming in the 90s was not pretty. While there is some sense of nostalgia around being intrinsically closer to the machine hardware on a daily basis, it's kind of good that those days are behind us. It was a total pain in the arse. Take comfort in the fact that you have access to better language tools, better APIs (_any_ APIs), better hardware, and infinitely more access to knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

In modern C++, it's recommended to use `new` paired with `delete` for memory management. If you use `delete`, you should not use `malloc`. Mixing memory allocation methods can lead to issues like memory leaks or undefined behavior. Stick to one method consistently.

Also, consider using smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` for safer memory management in modern C++.

Avoid mixing `malloc` with `delete`, as they use different mechanisms for memory management.

Comment: In modern C++ it's recommended to not use `new`, but if you *must*, then yeah, it pairs with `delete`. Your remark about `unique_ptr` is actually the important nugget here and should be given more prominence. Pointer wrappers solve all kinds of problems with basically zero additional overhead.

Comment: @tadman just want to emphasize that there is no zero overhead abstraction. For `std::unique_ptr`, please refer to https://youtu.be/rHIkrotSwcc?feature=shared&t=1005

Comment: @LouisGo: Moving complexity from runtime to compile time does not mean that the cost can't be zero. A template might take longer to compile--but then again, it might not. Explicitly invoking the dtor  can add enough more code that it takes longer to compile than the implicit invocation upon destroying a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: So when I was at school, I learned how to use malloc() and free() instead of delete which helped a lot. I appreciate your hep though!

Comment: @bullboi it's freaking annoying how frequently that happens. I hate having to retrain new hires in a language they're already supposed to know, and I'm not alone, so I recommend spending a bunch of time with [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/4581301) learning all the stuff you didn't learn or learned to do wrong in school.

Comment: @bullboi *So when I was at school* does not sound like self taught. I have no problems with self taught; for programming it's often better than what you get in school. *I learned how to use malloc() and free() instead of delete* `malloc` and friends  has it's place, but that place is down in the very bottom levels of the plumbing programs are built on top of, writing the code for implementing stuff like `new`, for example. If you are using it for anything else in C++, you are almost always "wrong". Schools that teach use of `malloc` for everything are very common and very wrong.

Comment: I am sorry for all of this stuff guys, I have tried new and delete and found it to be working & better. I appreciate all of you guys and I thank all of you for improving this coding journey.

Comment: You're good. Have a nice day and god bless you!